# Possible to use pushd/popd in Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile, pushd

Is there any way to use pushd/popd commands within a Dockerfile? It'd make some install scripts I have a lot easier if it were possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done but your image must have bash and all commands must be in the same `RUN` directive:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian
RUN mkdir -p /test/dir1/dir2
RUN bash -xc "\
pushd /test/dir1; \
pwd; \
pushd dir2; \
pwd; \
popd; \
pwd; \
"
RUN pwd
```

> ```
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  77.25MB
> Step 1/4 : FROM debian
>  ---> 2d337f242f07
> Step 2/4 : RUN mkdir -p /test/dir1/dir2
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> d609d5e33b08
> Step 3/4 : RUN bash -xc "pushd /test/dir1; pwd; pushd dir2; pwd; popd; pwd; "
>  ---> Running in 79aa21ebdd15
> + pushd /test/dir1
> + pwd
> + pushd dir2
> + pwd
> + popd
> + pwd
> /test/dir1 /
> /test/dir1
> /test/dir1/dir2 /test/dir1 /
> /test/dir1/dir2
> /test/dir1 /
> /test/dir1
> Removing intermediate container 79aa21ebdd15
>  ---> fb1a07d6e342
> Step 4/4 : RUN pwd
>  ---> Running in 9dcb064b36bb
> /
> Removing intermediate container 9dcb064b36bb
>  ---> eb43f6ed241a
> Successfully built eb43f6ed241a
> Successfully tagged test:latest
> ```